# Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1"

Tags: powershell, office-365, onedrive-for-business

I am working on some utility functions to ease the administration of our O365 tenant by importing some modules as part of my profile. The thing I'm working on currently is being able to provision One Drive for Business sites for users. I have the following code that works properly so far outside of a function but once I try to make it a function, I get the error in the title. What am I doing wrong here?

Works:

```
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com")
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($yourEmail,$SecurePassword)
    $Context.Credentials = $Credentials

    $Users = $Context.Web.SiteUsers
    $Context.Load($Users)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    write-host $Users.Count
```

Fails:

```
Function New-MySite{
    #Not Yet Implemented
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="A comma delimited string of email addresses",Position=1)][ValidateNotNull()]
        [string]$users,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Your email address",Position=0)][ValidateNotNull()]
        [string]$yourEmail
        )    
    $SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com")
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($yourEmail,$SecurePassword)
    $Context.Credentials = $Credentials

    $Users = $Context.Web.SiteUsers
    $Context.Load($Users)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    write-host $Users.Count
}
```

On Powershell 3 using the Powershell ISE client. Desired usage:

```
New-Mysite -yourEmail "eric@domain.com" -users "user1@domain.com"
```

Comment: Have you tried the method in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23609844) answer from SO?

Comment: I did see that, I'm on powershell v3, and honestly I'm not grasping what it is doing. Does the Powershell ISE run a different version?

Comment: Same problem on Powershell ISE Host Version 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, I was referencing the wrong DLLs. After altering my ISE profile to pull the 16 DLLs, this resolved itself.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same thing and was able to get this to work by replacing the commented out lines with the others.

```
# Add-Type -Path ([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client").location)
# Add-Type -Path ([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.runtime").location)
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client").location))
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.runtime").location))
```

`$host.version` is 4